# Is it possible to send workflow log to web server in real time?

Tags: github-actions

I cannot find any docs to handle this case, all I know is GitHub webhook but it seems to be for event notifications.
I have a Spring Boot server, when workflow was triggered I need to send detailed logs to my server in real time (I think websocket can do that).

Comment: Webhooks support [many events](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads), including [`workflow_run`](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#workflow_run), is that what you're looking for?

Comment: But it seem cannot sending detail log in realtime , have you suggest some third party support this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported by GitHub Actions itself. Though there probably is an API you could call to get the data, since the website is able to live-view the log. That API isn't officially supported and is undocumented.

Simplest solution I can think of is to run something on the runner machine that monitors the log folder of the agent and streams that out in realtime. Either installed permanently on a self-hosted runner or installed very early on in the workflow of the hosted-runner.

Or to [call the download logs API when the workflow run is finished](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#download-workflow-run-logs).

Comment: It working , thanks so much!!!

Comment: Can you add a comment or suggest an edit of my answer with what you ended up doing?

Comment: It is quite messy, but it simple.I just make a curl and send response in every step like this. I'll update my post when I have a better solution.